# Want to fix "word-break" so it works with non-ASCII punctuation and white space

Tags: css, internationalization, ascii, utf

I want to fix the functionality of css word-break property. Currently, it doesn't break on spaces and punctuation that aren't ascii. ”　” should be every bit as valid as " ", just as ”、” should be as valid as ",".

Not sure how to go about making a change like that happen. Does anyone know who to contact or if there is a repo I can access?

Comment: You have two options: **a)** contact W3C and convince them to change the standard; **b)** contact browser manufacturers and convince each of them to disregard the standard and implement it the way you want/need it. I'd say you need stronger arguments than what you laid here.

Comment: What kind of arguments are you suggesting? It seems self-explanatory that a word break should occur at a space or a comma.

Comment: Also, I'm not looking to "disregard the standard." I'm looking for the standard to be widened to include comma and spaces from scripts other than latin.

Comment: Jameela, your question [does not belong](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on [SO], as it's not a programming question. It's an administrative question asked at people who have no say in the matter. You can easily find out who regulates the web standards and use the available [communication channels](https://www.w3.org/participate/) to make a formal request.

Comment: Admin, or not, it's still a question about programming.  You say "easily" but it wasn't easy for me to find out hence the question. People who try to google something and then say "Here top 4 hits" often have a google search that is algorithmically dispositioned to knowing what you would look for. I haven't developed as long as a lot of people and haven't gone to school for it, so I often don't have the vocabulary needed to do a good online search, nor does google predict my needs as well. Also, why shame someone for trying to get information?

Comment: 1. Press "Ctrl + Shift + N". Google's *"algorithmic disposition"* just vanished. 2. Could you please point out the shaming part? I was genuinely trying to be informative. (Side-note:  I'm not against modifying the standard. but I believe it will take a lot of effort to actually happen).

Answer (score 0):

W3C's [line breaking specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#line-breaking) states

> In most writing systems, in the absence of hyphenation a soft wrap opportunity occurs only at word boundaries. Many such systems use spaces or punctuation to explicitly separate words, and soft wrap opportunities can be identified by these characters.

Browsers will perform a soft wrap on most Unicode white spaces, plus a few others. However by default characters do not delineate wrap opportunities. Characters such as ” are not wrap delineators by design.

---

If you has a defined list of characters that you wish to wrap you can use JavaScript to surround them with wrappable tags.

```js
punctuation = [ '”' ];

var paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll( 'p' );
for ( var p = 0; p < paragraphs.length; p++ ) {
    for ( var j = 0; j < punctuation.length; j++ ) {
        var re = new RegExp(punctuation[j], "g"),
            text = paragraphs[ p ].innerHTML;
        paragraphs[ p ].innerHTML = text.replace(re, '<wb>' + punctuation[j] + '</wb>');
    }
}
```

```css
wb {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>averylongworldconsistingof”words”runtogether”withsomenonbreaking”characters”averylongworldconsistingof”words”runtogether”withsomenonbreaking”characters”averylongworldconsistingof”words”runtogether”withsomenonbreaking”characters”averylongworldconsistingof”words”runtogether”withsomenonbreaking”characters</p>
```

Comment: I'm not speaking about quotation marks. I'm talking about commas and spaces used in the unicode character set marked at utf-16: "\u3001" rather than utf-16: "\u002c" and utf-16: "\u3000"  vs. utf-16: " ". I realize your answer is multi-applicable so thank you, but I'm specifically looking to change guidelines, and I'm not sure how to go about doing it.